# Web API 2, Identity 2 with Unity DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, unity-container

I am creating an API using web api 2 with Identity 2 also I am using Unity DI to resolve my dependency.

My code is working fine but the problem occurred when I try to register the user using Account Controller my ApplicationUserManager validation not working.

Here is my Code

Unity Config.cs

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        RegisterTypes(container);
        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
            new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static void RegisterTypes(UnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationUserManager>();
        container.RegisterType<MyContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();

        container.RegisterType<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>();
        container.RegisterType<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>();
        container.RegisterInstance(new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();

        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, CustomUserStore>(
            new InjectionConstructor(typeof(MyContext)));
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
            new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
        container.RegisterType<IOwinContext>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()));
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

My ConfigureAuth Function Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(HostedScormContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Now my AccountController

```
private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterUserDto model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var user = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        UserName = model.Username,
        Email = model.Email,
        Address1 = model.Address1,
        Address2 = model.Address2,
        Country = model.Country,
        City = model.City,
        State = model.State,
        ZipCode = model.ZipCode,
        Description = model.Description
    };

    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

when I hit the register API it does create a user but no validate the user like email is already registered etc. Al though I have Identity config.cs in my project but it seems its not working.

I also debug the code to check the UserManager object where I found my identityConfig setting somehow replaced like If I set Unique email true but in controller I get Unique email false.

How get validation wokring with UNITY DI